# How to get the number of rows in a table in a Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, count, size, google-cloud-datastore

In many cases, it could be useful to know the number of rows in a table (a kind) in a datastore using Google Application Engine. 
There is not clear and fast solution . At least I have not found one.. Have you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can efficiently get a count of all entities of a particular kind (i.e., number of rows in a table) using the [Datastore Statistics](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats.html).  Simple example:

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import stats
kind_stats = stats.KindStat().all().filter("kind_name =", "NameOfYourModel").get()
count = kind_stats.count
```

You can find a more detailed example of how to get the latest stats [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f2e7568040c015ff?pli=1) (GAE may keep multiple copies of the stats - one for 5min ago, one for 30min ago, etc.).

Note that these statistics aren't constantly updated so they lag a little behind the actual counts.  If you really need the actual count, then you could track counts in your own custom stats table and update it every time you create/delete an entity (though this will be quite a bit more expensive to do).

**Update 03-08-2015**: Using the Datastore Statistics can lead to stale results. If that's not an option, another two methods are keeping a counter or sharding counters. ([You can read more about those here](http://www.shiftedup.com/2015/03/08/how-to-count-all-entries-of-a-given-type-in-the-app-engine-datastore)). Only look at these 2 if you need real-time results.

Answer (score 7):

There's no concept of "Select count(*)" in App Engine. You'll need to do one of the following:

1. Do a "keys-only" (index traversal) of the Entities you want at query time and count them one by one. This has the cost of slow reads.
2. Update counts at write time - this has the benefit of extremely fast reads at a greater cost per write/update. Cost: you have to know what you want to count ahead of time. You'll pay a higher cost at write time.
3. Update all counts asynchronously using Task Queues, cron jobs or the new [Mapper API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce). This has the tradeoff of being semi-fresh.

Comment: +1 These are all great alternatives which might be more appropriate that the datastore statistics API depending on the needs of your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can count no. of rows in Google App Engine using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query  as follow:

```
   int count;   
   Query qry=new Query("EmpEntity");   
   DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
   count=datastoreService.prepare(qry).countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```