# Check if datastore is empty

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Quick and easy, what is the best way to check if a datastore is empty? Right now I'm doing         `if Map.all()` But there must be a way to do it with out having to do .all(), I imagine that its a little overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [count](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_count) method:

```
exists = Map.all().count(limit=1)
if exists: # it's not empty!
```

Comment: that's roughly what I did, I was kind of hoping there would be something so I didn't have to gather all of the map models. Also what does limit do for count?

Comment: The link for 'count' in my answer goes to the documentation.  There, it explains how 'limit' is a maximum for the number of items counted.  So in this example, it will stop counting after finding one Map entity.

Answer (score 1):

There's documentation on getting datastore stats programmatically [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats).

Comment: Is the answer here what you're talking about? Because I did not thing that was clear in the documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988864/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-in-a-datastore